# cross self join to get more rows - better solution?

Tags: mysql, join, insert, select

I have a table `employees`:

```
+----------------+------------------+
| Field          | Type             |
+----------------+------------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned |
| persons_id     | int(10) unsigned |
| restaurants_id | int(10) unsigned | 
+----------------+------------------+
```

and a table `bills`:

```
+----------------+------------------+
| Field          | Type             |
+----------------+------------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned |
| customers_id   | int(10) unsigned |
| employees_id   | int(10) unsigned |
| restaurants_id | int(10) unsigned |
| date           | date             |
+----------------+------------------+
```

I want to insert 10,000 rows with an `employees_id`, `restaurant_id` and a date into the table `bills` by using cross joins. The table `employees` is filled with 15 rows (employees).

Currently I do following:

```
insert into bills (employees_id, restaurants_id, date) select e.id, e.restaurants_id, '2012-01-01' from employees e cross join employees e2 cross join employees e3 cross join employees e4 order by RAND() limit 10000;
```

With this query I get 50,625 rows (without to limit to 10,000) (15rows*15rows*15rows*15rows=50,625rows). Is there an more elegant solution to get 10,000 rows? So I don't have to write X times `cross join employees eX`.

I'm using MySQL. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, their is no better way then cross joining on yourself *in MySQL*. You can make the SQL slightly more elegant using, say, a CTE in other RDBMS, but what you have is the best way IMO.

By "best", I include "efficient" too: set based/no loops, and no temp tables

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE emp1 SELECT id,restaurants_id FROM employees WHERE 1=2;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT id,restaurants_id FROM employees;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
INSERT INTO emp1 SELECT * FROM emp1;
CREATE TABLE emp2 SELECT id,restaurants_id FROM employees WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE emp2 ADD rnd INT NULL;
INSERT INTO emp2 (id,restaurants_id,rnd)
SELECT id,restaurants_id,RAND()*10000 FROM emp1 LIMIT 10000;
ALTER TABLE emp2 ADD INDEX (rnd);
DROP TABLE emp1;
INSERT INTO bills (employees_id, restaurants_id, date)
SELECT id,restaurants_id FROM emp2 ORDER BY rnd;
```

Comment: you call this more elegant?

Comment: @arminb, maybe it you should define what you mean by elegant :)

Comment: sorry i thought it's obvious. by elegant i meant a one-liner without creating temporary tables/variables etc. but thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use WHILE loop to do this.

```
SET num = 0

WHILE num < 10000 do

    INSERT INTO bills (employees_id, restaurants_id, date)
    SELECT id, restaurants_id, '2012-01-01' FROM employees WHERE id = 1 + RAND() * 16;

    SET num = num + 1

END WHILE;
```

In the above example, it selects a random employee where his id is between 1 and 15 (you said you have only 15 of them). This assumes that your employee IDs are sequential.

Comment: You can replace `WHERE id = 1 + RAND() * 16` with `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` - so no assumptions are made.

Comment: thanks for this. but i was looking for a one-line solution. nvm this was also useful for me.